# Pass array of files into the parameter of AWSCLI@1 task

Tags: azure-pipelines

- I'm using yaml pipelines
- I need to run aws cloudformation validate-template '--template-body "file://xxx' command
- I don't know **in advance** the filenames to validate
- So I need to do some kind of 'dir /L' and pass the results into the task
- this is the task which I'm using

```
  - task: AWSCLI@1
    displayName: Validate Template
    inputs:
        awsCommand: cloudformation
        awsSubCommand: validate-template
        awsArguments: '--template-body "file://$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/ec2.yml"'
        awsCredentials: $(awsCredentials)
        failOnStandardError: true
        regionName: eu-west-1
```

This task validates only one file, how to do 'foreach' loop here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pass array of files into the parameter of AWSCLI@1 task

> We are passing value to template parameters, so you can't build the - test1 -
> test2 dynamically.

As a workaround, we can create another pipeline. In this pipeline, we add two powershell tasks. In the first task, we set a variable with tables as the value.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
     inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: 'Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=filenames]files1,files2,files3"'
```

In the second task, we use [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#loop-through-parameters) to trigger the `pipeline.yml` pipeline. In the request body, we use the variable set in the first task as the value of the template parameter.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $token = "PAT"
      $url="https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"
      $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
      
      $JSON = @'
      {
        "templateParameters": {
          "file":"[$(filenames)]"
         },
      }
      '@
      
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
```

Below is my test sample:

```
### pipeline.yml ###
parameters:
  - name: file
    type: object
    default: {}

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:  
- template: template1.yml
  parameters:
    files: ${{ parameters.file}}
```

template.yml:

```
### template1.yml ###
parameters:
  - name: "files"
    type: object
    default: {}
 
steps:
   - ${{ each file in parameters.files}}:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: echo "${{ file}}"
```

Then we run the newly created pipeline to trigger the `pipeline.yml` pipeline, get the result:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? I'm getting error`
Validation
/loopTemplate.yml (Line: 6, Col: 3): Expected a sequence or mapping. Actual value '$(AllFileNames)'`
AFAIK, variables in azure pipelines can only be strings, not arrays.

Comment: after changing ```files : $(AllFileNames)
``` to ```files :  
- $(AllFileNames)``` yam is lavid but the results is one big string of filenames separated by space. There is ony one step instead of 4.

Comment: @ALIENQuake, We can try to parse $FileNames='"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"' to the result is `- test1`  another line  `- test2`

Comment: What do you mean by 'parse'? We are passing value to template parameters, so you can't  build the ```- test1 - test2``` dynamically.

Comment: @ALIENQuake, If you pass value to template parameters, there is a workaround to do that, please check my update answer.

Comment: That looks amazing! I'm feeling that you just hack the planet, thank you!

Comment: BTW: There is a typo ```- ${{ each files in parameters.files}}:```  - should be ```- ${{ each file in parameters.files }}:``` - ```file``` without 's'

Comment: And universal $url can be like this: ```$url="$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"```

Comment: @ALIENQuake, Yes, that should be my copy error, updated it, thanks for the info.